ffmpeg.exe error "There are 2 hardware devices. device cuda0 of type cuda is picked for filters by default"
Two different users (as far) reported this error using my Electron app that has the ability to record the game play and cut replays as highlights:
They have a 4060 and a 3060. I have also a 3060 and (naturally) this error doesn't happen for me.
We have checked also nvidia-smi output and only one NVidia device is registered. One of them tried also to disable the built-in GPU adapter from the CPU but no luck.
The error in particular is: "There are 2 hardware devices. device cuda0 of type cuda is picked for filters by default. Set hardware device explicitly with the filter_hw_device option if device cuda0 is not usable for filters."
Here it the command line and ffmpeg execution log:
[2024-12-18 00:46:10.210] [info]  Executing ffmpeg.exe -nostats -hide_banner -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -init_hw_device d3d11va -filter_complex ddagrab=offset_x=0:offset_y=0:video_size=1920x1080:framerate=60 -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -f dshow -i audio=@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{2EBD7673-1FDC-4624-B31B-E3850A00954A} -ar 44100 -f dshow -i audio=@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{2EBD7673-1FDC-4624-B31B-E3850A00954A} -ar 44100 -filter_complex [1:a][2:a]amerge=inputs=2[a] -map 0:v -map [a] -colorspace bt709 -color_trc bt709 -color_primaries bt709 -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 2500k -preset p3 -rc:v vbr -cq 27 -profile:v high -tune hq -rc-lookahead 30 -spatial-aq 1 -bf 2 -g 60 -acodec aac -fps_mode passthrough -f mpegts -
[2024-12-18 00:46:10.472] [info]  [info] [gdigrab @ 00000242f62ea540] Capturing whole desktop as 1920x1080x32 at (0,0)

[2024-12-18 00:46:10.557] [info]  [info] [gdigrab @ 00000242f62ea540] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize

[2024-12-18 00:46:10.559] [info]  [info] Input #0, gdigrab, from 'desktop':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1734482770.491128, bitrate: 3981337 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 1920x1080, 3981337 kb/s, 60 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn

[2024-12-18 00:46:11.649] [info]  [info] [aist#1:0/pcm_s16le @ 00000242f62f2140] Guessed Channel Layout: stereo
Input #1, dshow, from 'audio=@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{2EBD7673-1FDC-4624-B31B-E3850A00954A}':
  Duration: N/A, start: 107919.758000, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
  Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s

[2024-12-18 00:46:12.271] [info]  [info] [aist#2:0/pcm_s16le @ 00000242f6364f40] Guessed Channel Layout: stereo
Input #2, dshow, from 'audio=@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{2EBD7673-1FDC-4624-B31B-E3850A00954A}':
  Duration: N/A, start: 107920.393000, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
  Stream #2:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s

[2024-12-18 00:46:12.467] [info]  [info] Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 (pcm_s16le) -> amerge (graph 1)
  Stream #2:0 (pcm_s16le) -> amerge (graph 1)
  ddagrab:default (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (h264_nvenc)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (bmp (native) -> h264 (h264_nvenc))
  amerge:default (graph 1) -> Stream #0:2 (aac)

[2024-12-18 00:46:12.469] [info]  [info] Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
There are 2 hardware devices. device cuda0 of type cuda is picked for filters by default. Set hardware device explicitly with the filter_hw_device option if device cuda0 is not usable for filters.

[2024-12-18 00:46:12.473] [info]  [info]     Last message repeated 1 times
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 00000242f62f0340] No channel layout for input 1

[2024-12-18 00:46:12.476] [info]  [info] [Parsed_amerge_0 @ 00000242f62f0340] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
[Parsed_ddagrab_0 @ 00000242f62ef140] Non-D3D11VA input hw_device_ctx
[Parsed_ddagrab_0 @ 00000242f62ef140] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_ddagrab_0
[fc#0 @ 00000242f62e6200] Error configuring filter graph: Invalid argument
[fc#0 @ 00000242f62e6200] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[fc#0 @ 00000242f62e6200] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)

[2024-12-18 00:46:12.482] [info]  [info] There are 2 hardware devices. device cuda0 of type cuda is picked for filters by default. Set hardware device explicitly with the filter_hw_device option if device cuda0 is not usable for filters.

[2024-12-18 00:46:13.042] [info]  [info] [vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 00000242fdaa6c80] [enc:h264_nvenc @ 00000242f634c280] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 00000242fdaa6c80] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 00000242fdaa6c80] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)

[2024-12-18 00:46:13.092] [info]  [info] [out#0/mpegts @ 00000242f62ef680] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lq=13.0 size=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A    

[2024-12-18 00:46:13.212] [info]  [info] [aac @ 00000242f6398bc0] Qavg: 116.716

[2024-12-18 00:46:13.286] [info]  [info] Conversion failed!

[2024-12-18 00:46:13.338] [info]  FFmpeg process exited with code 4294967274
[2024-12-18 00:46:13.339] [error] ffmpeg closed with error 4294967274

Thanks!

1. Did you try to "set hardware device explicitly with the filter_hw_device"? 2. I recommend you to post the minimal example that reproduces the problem. Try the following two commands (for example): ffmpeg.exe -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -init_hw_device d3d11va -filter_complex ddagrab=offset_x=0:offset_y=0:video_size=1920x1080:framerate=60 -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -c:v h264_nvenc -t 5 test1.mp4 and ffmpeg.exe -y -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -init_hw_device d3d11va -f gdigrab -framerate 60 -i desktop -c:v h264_nvenc -t 5 test2.mp4
